# Initialize a arbitrary number of fields

Tags: r, reference-class

Is the function initFields not a good way to initialize arbitrary fields of a reference class? If not what would you suggest? And how could I handle the a field of type "ANY", because for the string "ANY" I cant do a call like `do.call(fields[[i]],list())`

```
Part.initFields<-function(args){
  argNames <- names(args)
  fields<-.self$getRefClass()$fields()
  fieldNames <- names(fields)
  for(i in seq_along(fields)){
     var <- if(is.null(args[[fieldNames[i]]])) do.call(fields[[i]],list())
            else do.call(paste("as.",fields[[i]],sep=""),list(args[[fieldNames[i]]]))
     assign(fieldNames[[i]], var, attr(.self, ".xData"))
   }
 }

Part.initialize<-function(...){
  args<-list(...)
  .self$initFields(args)
  .self
}

Part<-setRefClass(Class = "Part"
                 ,fields = c(var1 = "numeric", var2 = "character")
                 ,methods = list(initialize=Part.initialize
                                ,initFields=Part.initFields))

part<-Part$new(var1=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the initialize method to coerce arguments. Explicitly exclude
coercions that you do no wish to perform. Coerce using `as(x, "class")` instead of trying to construct function names from character strings. Do not re-implement
`initFields`.

```
Part <- setRefClass(Class = "Part",
    fields=c(var0 = "ANY", var1 = "numeric", var2 = "character"),
    methods=list(
      initialize=function(...) {
          args <- list(...)
          map <- .self$getRefClass()$fields(); map <- map[map != "ANY"]
          idx <- names(args) %in% names(map)
          args[idx] <- Map(as, args[idx], map[names(args)[idx]])
          do.call(.self$initFields, args)
      }))
```

Simple test cases

```
Part()
Part(var2=1:3)
```